# Nvidia GTX 780 + Late 2009 Mac Pro

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, mac-pro

For the record driver compatibility is not an issue, as I don't use OSX any more (Kubuntu Linux).

I'm upgrading my Mac Pro 2009 (http://support.apple.com/kb/SP506) with an Nvidia GTX 780 (http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-780/specifications); I've heard that there may be power consumption/burnout issues (http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1565650). The Nvidia website says I should have a power supply capable of 600 watts, and that the card would draw 250 watts (some forums say the card regularly exceeds even that).

I don't want to buy a lower card on account of my machines specs, as I'd like this card for whatever future computer I may build. So I need to ask; Will I risk burning out my machine if I use this card? Are there any steps or notes for running this card safely? Or will it run just fine if I install it correctly with the adapter?

As a note the majority of work I'll be doing will be video encoding and digital graphics; I do game, but I don't play particularly graphics-intense games (E.g. Amnesia) - I'm just looking for a long-term investment and the ability to play at 2560x1600. So when I do max out the card, I doubt it will be for extended periods.

---

**UPDATE:**
Further research! It looks like Early 2009 power supplies are 980 watts (http://www.ebay.com/bhp/apple-mac-pro-power-supply); So now it's all a question if using this card will burn out the board in any way...

---

**UPDATE:**
The 2009 mac pro (and some other models) require 2x mini 6-pin power connections, and a 6-pin to 8-pn converter. So if you have similar plans, be sure to get the mini 6-pin to standard 6-pin connectors; they can be hard to find, so it would pay to locate a pair in advance or order ahead of time. Currently waiting on mine to be shipped before closing this question.

Comment: If you don't have a power supply with the ability to provide the card enough power it simply won't work.  I am pretty sure you can replace the power supply with a standard ATX power supply.  If you don't have at least a 600w its very likely your system won't even boot.

Comment: Thanks Ramhound... After further poking, I just found out the power supply is capable of 980 watts - which makes sense since Mac pros try to use server-grade components. (updated the question)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphics card and PSU requirement](http://superuser.com/questions/1035218/graphics-card-and-psu-requirement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will using this card burn out the board in any way?

You have all the required specifications for the card to work.